# Is 1...d5 ever a bad move?

Tags: opening

I notice that as Black, I virtually always play d5 as my first move. It's usually in response to 1. e4 (Scandinavian Defense) or 1. d4 (Queen's Pawn Game).  As a hypothetical, if I premoved 1... d5, what is the worst that could happen? Are there any openings in which it is not a strong move?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Against `1.c4`. This will allow white to exchange their c-pawn for black d-pawn and later gain a tempo. `2. cxd5 Qxd5 3.Nc3`, or `2...Nf6` at some point will be followed with `e4` with tempo. All in all, white can take control of the center.

According to [lichess'](https://lichess.org/) database `1.c4 d5` is very rarely played.

However, the move is probably not losing; stockfish gives it: 0.6. The significance of this advantage varies a lot depending on the player's strength.

Comment: 2...Nf6 can be met with 3.e4! because of 3....Nxe4? Qa4+

Comment: I'm not claiming 2 ... Nf6 is wonderful, but after 3 e4 c6 4 dxc6 Nxc6 5 Nc3 e5 Black has some compensation for the pawn gambitted - I've definitely seen worse (most often on my own board)

Comment: @IanBush you're right and I wouldn't be surprised if 3.d4 were a better move than 3.e4

Comment: Everything in this answer also holds for 1. e4 d5, even the SF evaluation matches

Comment: @B.Swan, I think there are some differences that make 1.c4 d5 more favorable for white then 1.e4 d5. 1. White still has two center pawns, so they can get stronger control of the center. 2. In 1.e4 d5, even though the knight jumps to c3 with tempo, it blocks the c-pawn, which makes it a little bit harder for white to coordinate, in 1.c4 d5, the c-pawn is already traded, so it is not an issue.

Comment: @B.Swan. Bobby Fischer's opinion of 1. e4 d5 was so low that when Addison played it against him in the Interzonal of 1970, Fischer smiled, and quickly wiped him out.